# Make request to explicitly given IP, but use explicitly given hostname for the purpose of SSL verification?

Tags: php, https, guzzle

Is there a way to **simultaneously** tell `GuzzleHttp\Client` to:

- send the request to an explicitly given IP, and
- "pretend" for the purpose of SSL verification that the request is being made to a specific hostname?

For reasons that are beyond the scope of this question, I **cannot** simply pass "https://some.host.name/uri" as the request URL. I **must** pass https://<some-numerical-IP>/uri" and set the `Host` header. However when I do this, Guzzle ignores the `Host` header for the purpose of SSL host and peer verification and tries to use the numerical IP address, which fails.

How do I GetWhatIWant™?

Comment: Can you use `/etc/hosts` to override the DNS for `some.host.name` to the correct IP?

Comment: No, for several reasons: I need wildcards, and the IP may change (but will be known at the moment of making the request).
Generally I will prefer solutions contained to GuzzleHttp. I will choose a solution that involves DNS configuration only when a Guzzle-only solution is conclusively proven to be impossible.

Comment: Seems like a design flaw, but why not after determining the IP `$host = gethostbyaddr($ip);` then use `$host`?

Comment: No, hostname is *given*, because certificates.

Comment: _For reasons that are beyond the scope of this question_ to get any help it will have to be IN SCOPE for the question, or you've just built an unusable system.

Comment: No, the constraints are absolutely clear: 1) hostname is given at the time of each request, but may change from request to request; 2) IP is given at the time of each request, but may change from request to request, 3) need to make GuzzleHttp behave *as if* the hostname mapped to the IP with the DNS the client is using; 4) actually configuring DNS for this purpose is to be avoided. A solution satisfying these constraints either objectively exists, or objectively doesn't exist. Everything else is truly outside the scope of this question.

Comment: You're being quizzed on the reasons because this sounds a lot like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Knowing the reasons may steer you towards a better *solution* than the one you've decided is the only option.

Comment: It *may* be an XY problem, but it has been overwhelmingly my experience that actually sticking to Y is the better strategy most of the time, all things considered. Specifically, avoiding spending weeks or months shifting your paradigms from Y to Y' is a HUGE thing to consider.

Comment: In short: the question whether a problem is an XY problem should only be asked *after* Y is conclusively and authoritatively ruled out as a possible solution, *not before or instead of*.

Comment: It's been overwhelmingly our experience that's not the case. That's why Wikipedia calls it [a "communication problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), http://xyproblem.info/ exists, and the meta thread exists.

Comment: Agree to disagree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the "XY problem" talk in the comments notwithstanding, this turned out to be a 100% pure "Y problem", and here is [the solution](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/362#issuecomment-164243440):

```php
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'curl' => [CURLOPT_RESOLVE => ['fakedomain.dev:80:127.0.0.1']],
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with host headers on the request instead of setting the `curl` option. I was never able to get it to work with host headers on the Client.  We use this approach since the place we need to make use of it is passed a GuzzleHttp `client` and doesn't get to create it.

```php
    $client = new Client([
            // Connect to local host
            'base_uri' => "https://127.0.0.1/",
            'timeout' => 2.0,
            'verify' => false, //we're connecting to localhost,
            // Documentation seems says you can do this, however it doesn't seem to work
//            'headers' => [
//                    'Host' => $host
//            ]
        ]);


        $response = $client->request('GET', '/some/url', [
            'headers' => [
                'Host' => 'fakedomain.dev'
            ]
        ]);
```